# Automatically switch default sound device when bluetooth headset switches between stereo and handsfree modes

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headphones, wireless-headset

Bluetooth headsets in general (or just most of them?) can only do one of the following:

1. Play stereo sound (or "high quality" sound in general)
2. Play mono/restricted sound and take mic input

but not both.

This means that when I get a call for example, the rest of the system is effectively muted while the communications program is using the HandsFree driver of the headset.

I'd like an option to allow the system to automatically switch back and forth between modes. So that:

1. If some application requires the mic, default everything to the mono driver
2. If no applications require the mic, default to the stereo/good driver